# Describing a certain quality of an image

Tags: image-processing, terminology

Generally I guess I’m asking for a source of image processing terminology.

Specifically here I’m trying to find the word for the quality that would identify the main difference between the Mondriaan on the left and the Monet on the right. Graphical/strong edges vs no solid areas and no well-defined edges.

I know a good amount about image processing but this vocab part is a glaring omission for me. [image: image-teem]

Comment: Do you want to describe the image pixels distribution or the contours the image contains?

Comment: It's related more to the lack of strong contours/edges.  Put another way: a simple blur filter, applied over and over, would end up producing a solid value on the right side of the above image before it would on the left side.   That's the quality I'm trying to name.

Answer (score 1):

The Monet image appears to have a much higher entropy.  Whereas the Mondrian image looks like it could very likely be compressed losslessly into a lower number of bits (depending on the compression method) due to a lower informational entropy.

Comment: It’s related to compression. Visually and qualitatively the Money has a “smoother” and less jarring appearance to it. Think continuous vs step function. Like if you defocused the above, you’d lose the features of the Monet long before the Mondriaan. 

Entropy sounds like a great term for it.